# When querying SQL, time that passed to query is less 2 hours of the time I set. Why?

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle, extjs

please advise.
Working with ExtJS, and Oracle SQL. Situation is this:
I have to get documents from DB, between two dates, `dateFrom` and `dateTo`. 
My `dateTo` is set to end of Current day, eg 2018-02-09 23:59:59.

```
let dateTo = new Date()    
dateTo = Ext.Date.clearTime(dateTo);
dateTo.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
```

When I query, dates passed are both less 2 hours of what I have set (2018-02-09 21:59:59). Why is this happening, someone? Is it because of this GMT+2 business?
`capture1.png` is from SQL query, `capture2.png` is `console.log(dateTo)`
And how to cure it. 
Many thanks in advance!

[image: SQL query]

[image: console.log(dateTo)]

Comment: May be due to daytime saving

Comment: Looks like the date you provided is being converted from local time zone to UTC, yes.Without seeing what's happening in between the `setHours()` and  SQL call, no idea at what point. Possibly related to [`getTime()` always giving UTC?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Comment: Alex, DB call follows right after I set time to 23:59:59.. Wondering how to prevent it from subtracting 2 hours.. I am right, that at current state of thing, I only get docs from DB that are up to 21:59:59? Cheers

Comment: What is the datatype of the column in the db ?

Comment: Does your ExtJS frontend communicate with database directly? When I stumbled on the same issue, the problem was neither in the frontend nor in the database, but in the backend logic (you don't say what you use: C#, PHP, JSF...)... where C# used weird `DateTimeKind` settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the date by subtracting the GMT Diff

- gmtDiff = Ext.Date.format(dateTo, 'Z') * 1000

and then to see the result:

- Ext.Date.format(dateTo, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')